# Output of printf("%d") with no additional arguments

Tags: c, linux

What will be the output of `printf("%d");` or `printf("%p");` statement?

Of course I know that I should pass argument as printf is expecting one but assuming that I will leave this empty what will happen?

I know that this will print some value read from stack (from the place where function argument should be placed). Assuming that I am running Linux machine can I expect that this will be some valid value (e.g. function return address)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simply undefined behaviour. Anything could happen. It's impossible to give a more accurate answer.

The details depend on how `printf` is implemented by the library, and how variable arguments are implemented by your compiler. Look at the source of the library and/or the generated assembly to find out what's happening on *your* platform.

Comment: Isn't it that while evaluating printf("%d"); expression first argument "%d" will be taken from the stack and based on the specifier %d next value will be taken? In this case something that is located on the stack after first argument ("%d"). Will it really produce undefined behaviour?

Comment: @codewarrior: The question "will it really produce UB" makes no sense. It is *defined* to be UB. So yes, it is indeed UB.

Comment: @codewarrior it won't necessarily be taken "from the stack". On my Linux, the code compiled with gcc prints the contents of the CPU register `%esi`. This answer is correct: check your generated assembly.

Answer (score 2):

This invokes undefined behavior. By its very nature, this means you can't assume anything about what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

This provokes undefinded behaviour. You might get printed out a random integer or a crash or ...

Comment: You might not get as far as printing.

Comment: I adusted my answer to be less optimistic ... @ta.speot.is

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior. Which means your program can for example crash.

> (C99, 7.19.6.1p2) "If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined."

Answer (score 0):

*can I expect that this will be some valid value*? : NO.